# Chronicle Bytes: How to write bytes in big endian order on a little endian machine?

Tags: java, chronicle, chronicle-bytes

I'm using the `Bytes<U>` interface from [here](https://javadoc.io/doc/net.openhft/chronicle-bytes/latest/index.html). The underlying buffer is created as follow:

```
Bytes<?> buf = Bytes.elasticHeapByteBuffer(MAX_SIZE);
buf.writeLong(l);   // writes in little endian
```

Given my machine byte order is little endian, how can I write the bytes in big endian instead?

Thank you.

Edit:
According to this [chart](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Bytes#comparison-of-access-to-native-memory), it seems like chronicle bytes does not support this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying implementation uses whatever is the native byte order of the CPU. i.e. little-endian on amd64 and ARM, big-endian on Sparc.

You can swap the order with

```
Bytes<?> buf = Bytes.elasticHeapByteBuffer(MAX_SIZE);
buf.writeLong(Long.reverseLong(l));

long l2 = Long.reverseLong(buf.readLong(l));
```

Most computers these days are little-endian so it's only an issue when sharing data with a big-endian system.